# How can I remove an image from FTP vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, ftp, delete-file

I looking for a code to remove images from FTP but does'nt work
I tried to use this code but not work for me:

```
 Dim FTPRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftpname.es/Html/images/" & imagename), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    FTPRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("FTPUsername", "FTPPassword")
    FTPRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile
    FTPRequest.UsePassive = True
    FTPRequest.UseBinary = True
    FTPRequest.KeepAlive = False
```

How can I remove images from ftp?
Thanks

Comment: "not work for me" doesn't tell us *anything* about what happens when you try that code...

Comment: Ftprequest.doIt()  '' ? Connect/get response

Comment: when I say does'nt work I mean that with this code not remove the image from the ftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this code not remove the image from the ftp

That's because you never actually execute it, you just initialize it. To issue a `WebRequest`, you need to get its response:

```
var response = FTPRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now the code works correctly to me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the FtpClient class?

```
Dim client as new System.Net.FtpClient.FtpClient()
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTPUsername", "FTPPassword")
client.Host = "ftp://myftpname.es"
client.Connect()

client.DeleteFile("Html/images/" & imageName)
```